Cant ping domain inside its server [DNS, Coludflare]
I have website halorumah.id, recently I migrate the server to local provider(in Indonesia), I am  also using Cloudflare because I need its cdn/cache feature, my domain is successfully using Cloudflare, but the problem is :

I tried dig halorumah.id +trace @1.1.1.1 , the result is halorumah.id is not reachable
I tried ping halorumah.id from its server, the result is : 100% loss package
I tried ping another server/domain from server halorumah.id, its 100% worked
I tried pinging another server(subdomain) base.halorumah.id from its own server and from my local pc, its working 100% success
I have a firewall in VPS, all Apache is allowed

Another info, I am using apache server with php-fpm
My domain is fully proxied to Cloudflare (full DNS managed). The question is why does this happen?

Can you give us exact output of dig halorumah.id +trace @1.1.1.1?
